# how to read multiple variables separated by commas using only C fscanf()

Tags: c, file-io, scanf

Say Given a text file that looks like this:

```
a,b,c
x,y,z
```

where a is a char *, b contains a float and c contains a double. 
For an example, the input file can look like this:

```
apple,$12.34,test130.8
x,y,z
```

I want to use fscanf() to read a, b, c and assign each one of them to a corresponding variable.
"apple" will be assigned to A of the same data type; "12.34"(not "$12.34") will be assigned to B with a float data type; so on.

My attempt was as follows:

```
fp = the file pointer

char A[50];
float B;
double C;

fscanf(fp, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,]\n", A, B, C);
```

But I realized that `%[^,]`can only specify type char *; ergo, I'm not allowed to assign type char * to a float or double variable.
Is there a way to parse `%[^,]` to make it only specifies type float?

if I only use this:

```
fscanf(fp, "%s,%f,%lf\n", A, B, C);
```

It will be thrown off by the "$" in "12.34", and it will give me 0.000000.

Comment: nowhere are you dealing with the $ sign, you cannot read "$12.4" into a float

Comment: Minrui L, Try `fscanf(fp, "%49[^,],$%f,test%lf", A, &B, &C);`

Comment: Minrui L, What should happen when input does not follow  the expected format?

Comment: Yo, Thank you guys! I figured it out. Forgot to deal with "$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sscanf()` (instead of `fscanf()`) for ease of testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *s = "apple,$12.34,test130.8\npear,$23.45,abc";
    for(int offset = 0, n;; offset += n) {
        char *symbol;
        float price;
        char *note;
        if(sscanf(s + offset, " %m[^,],$%f,%m[^\n]%n", &symbol, &price, &note, &n) != 3) {           
            break;
        }
        printf("symbol: %s, price: %f, note: %s\n", symbol, price, note);
        free(note);
        free(symbol);
    }
}
```

and the matching output (note how it demonstrate the evils of using floating points for money):

```
symbol: apple, price: 12.340000, note: test130.8
symbol: pear, price: 23.450001, note: abc
```

I used `%m` to have `scanf()` allocate the strings.  If I knew the maximum size of the strings I would reuse a fixed size strings instead of dynamically allocating and freeing those.

When using `fscanf()` instead of break you could use `feof()` to see if we are done, or if the input is invalid.  If it's invalid you may want to resync to the next `\n` with `fsccnf(..., "%c", ch)`.  For the above `s[offset] == '\0'` will tell if you are the end but see below.

You may find it's much easier to get a line with `fgets()`, then use `sscanf()` similar to above to extract each item.  If fails you can report the line and just read the next one.  `fgets()` will return `NULL` if you have no more data and it leads to cleaner code when you separate I/O and parsing.

Comment: Definitely looking into `fgets()`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's already an answer from @AllanWind (using dynamic allocation for strings that my old library doesn't do.) Here's an alternative solution (that is much the same.)

First, the input file used for testing:

```
apple,$12.34,test130.8
banana,$20.67,testing201.45
```

Then the code using `fscanf()` with a complicated format string:

```
int main( void ) {
    FILE *fp = fopen( "test.txt", "r" );
    if( fp == NULL) {
        fprintf( stderr, "fopen() failed\n" );
        return -1;
    }

    char txt[50], word[12];
    double dval1, dval2;

    while( fscanf( fp, " %49[^,],%*c%lf,%11[^0123456789]%lf", txt, &dval1, word, &dval2 ) == 4 )
        printf( "'%s' / %.2lf / '%s' / %.2lf\n", txt, dval1, word, dval2 );

    fclose( fp );

    return 0;
}
```

Finally, the output

```
'apple' / 12.34 / 'test' / 130.80
'banana' / 20.67 / 'testing' / 201.45
```

Comment: Good answer but it's [risky](https://everydayastronaut.com/mars-climate-orbiter/) to ignore the unit.

Comment: @AllanWind Good point. My heart goes out to all the disregarded coders who noticed but whose voices were squelched by managers who "knew better."...